# How can I make an array around deformed object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create a ventilation so I made this:
[image]
I have a rib (near cursir) and I want to create an array of that's ribs along my mesh. How can I do that? I've tried to use object offset in array modifier but without result:
[image]
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a plane, give it an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier:

[image]

In the *Object panel > Instancing* > enable *Faces*:

[image]

Parent your rib to the plane, it will duplicate the rib (now you can hide the plane in the *Object* panel and hide the original rib):

[image]

Comment: I have problems on the first step. How you get this curve? Should I create it and try to adjust to original mesh?

Comment: Yes you need to create the curve, to have perpendicular angles you need to select all the vertices and press V > Vector. You could also duplicate an edge loop of your current object, separate it as a new object and convert it to curve?

Comment: Thank you! It works.